# Chrome 302 redirect and removing session variables

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, redirect

I got a problem related to this Chrome bug:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=114977#c5

I am making a poll where after filling page, data is being post to itself and after writting it to $_SESSION redirects with 302 to next step. But it seems that session variables that at first seem to be available from PHP script, after refresh or next redirect are being set back to the ones that were at beginning (before first redirect). It works well in every other browser, even IE.

Is there any solution to that problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue in asp.net with Response.Redirect(). Only Chromium based browsers have this issue. I tested it against Opera 12 (Presto) and Opera 16 (Chromium) as well. I am still debugging our site to try and figure out a solution. If I find something that could be related I will let you know.